# how to display the results of an array

Tags: arrays

I created an array with list of product names.  I want to display the list.  When the following runs, it simply shows me the last entry in the array, not the list of items in the array.

```
whileprintingrecords;
Shared stringvar array premium;
numbervar x := 1;
stringvar showit;

for x := 1 to 5 do
(
showit := premium[x];
x := x+1;
);

showit;
```

If I move the last line to within the () then I get True as the response.

Answer (score 1):

You "overwrite" the variable showit on every for loop, thus premium[5] will be the last value assigned to showit (at first, showit was premium[1], then premium[2] and so on)

Comment: Ok, I follow.  If I move "showit" inside the loop to catch the value for each iteration, all I get is TRUE not the 5 values.  Any suggestions on how to display each of the 5 values in the array?

    whileprintingrecords;
    Shared stringvar array premium;
    numbervar x := 1;
    stringvar showit;
    
    
    for x := 1 to 5 do
    (
    showit := premium[x];
    
    showit;
    
    x := x+1;
    );

Comment: You can show each index variable at her loop, for example at the first loop you show premium[1] : for x := 1 to 5 do ( //and here you show premium[x] )

Answer (score 0):

To show the iterations in the array on new lines, the final solution uses the Join function. Much simpler coding.

```
whileprintingrecords;
Shared stringvar array premium;

join(premium, ChrW(13));
```